# Autocomplete experimental messages option, no results

Tags: jquery, jquery-ui, jquery-ui-autocomplete

I moved to jQuery UI 1.9 and have some problems with Autocomplete control. As written [here](http://jqueryui.com/upgrade-guide/1.9/#added-experimental-messages-option-for-accessibility) they added option called `messages` that actually shows "No results" or results count information under the control. The problem that I can't any info about its behaviour find in the [manuals](http://api.jqueryui.com/autocomplete/).

How can I disable that option? Thank you

Comment: > If you're interested in the messages option, we encourage you to just read the source; the relevant code is at the very bottom of the autocomplete plugin and is only a few lines.

Comment: Yes, I saw that. But why there are no any information in API documentation? Or they mean If I don't need such feature I should to remove it from source code?

Comment: may be set option to something... that experimental feature, so it not documented

Comment: really strange.. the final release and there are some undocumented options that are enabled by default..

Comment: they do many strange thing, main site is worse now than it was, early we had api documentation in demos, now not

Comment: So I just removed that code from sources.

Comment: WARNING: You shouldn't disable or remove with accessibility in name unless you understand that code completely and you know why you want to remove it. And I doubt this was the case. The message would be normally invisible to you if you also updated the stylesheet for the plugin. But it helps a lot to disabled users. **Please do not remove this message. Use the same styling for the `.ui-helper-hidden-accessible` class as e.g.Bootstrap uses for `.sr-only` instead.**

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Indeed **not** in the [API documentation](http://api.jqueryui.com/autocomplete/) to the date of my answer... You can customize it this way:

```
  jQuery(...).autocomplete({
     messages : {
      noResults : 'No results found.',
      results : function(count) {
        return count + (count > 1 ? ' results' : ' result ') + ' found';
      }
    },
  });
```

NOTE: As commented by user actimel, customising is ok but do not hide it as it is part of the accessibility feature (blind users for example).

Comment: I have extensivelly searched the jqueryui documentation and have found no refferences to this behavior/property. I am uttery blind?

Comment: @Honza This is exactly what I say it is not documented (or at least was not when I posted this)

Comment: You can customize the wording, but please do not try to disable or remvoe this accessibility feature. See my comment above.

Answer (score 0):

I have been digging around this a bit and found the following:

The message is part of jQuery UI accessibility functionality and is actually never supposed to be shown (visible) and only processed by screen-readers.

All your problems will go away if you use some of the jQuery UI stylesheet files that will hide these elements for you.