# JqueryUI autocomplete error: Uncaught TypeError: Property 'results' of object #<Object> is not a function

Tags: jquery, json, jquery-ui, asp.net-mvc-4, autocomplete

I've looked around and can't find an answer to my problem. I have not used jquery UI much, but I'm trying to implement an autocomplete using this blog entry [jQuery UI Autocomplete with JSON in MVC 4](http://www.itorian.com/2013/02/jquery-ui-autocomplete-with-json-in-mvc.html) as a guide because it's practically identical to what I need. I'm probably missing something "obvious" because I don't understand all the pieces of the autocomplete syntax yet.

**Issue:** I can get the dropdown of suggestions to appear. But as soon as it does I get a

```
 Uncaught TypeError: Property 'results' of object #<Object> is not a
 function
```

error in the console. 
Also, though the suggestions appear, I can't select any of them. the list disappears as soon as I try. Though that could be something else altogether.

The location of the error in the jqueryUI1.9.2 code is the last line in this snippet:

```
__response: function( content ) {
    var message;
    this._superApply( arguments );
    if ( this.options.disabled || this.cancelSearch ) {
        return;
    }
    if ( content && content.length ) {
        message = this.options.messages.results( content.length );
```

My jquery looks like this:

```
    $("#FastCategory").autocomplete({
        source: function (request, response) {
            $.ajax({
                url: "/Quiz/GetCategory",
                type: "POST",
                dataType: "json",
                data: { term: request.term },
                success: function (data) {
                    console.log("data=",data);
                    response($.map(data, function (item) {
                        console.log("item=",item,item.Description);
                        return { label: item.Description, value: item.Description };
                    }))
                }
            })
        },
        messages: {
            noResults: "", results: ""
        }
    });
```

My controller looks like this:

```
public JsonResult GetCategory(string term)
{
    var result = (from r in db.QuizCategories
                  where r.Description.ToLower().Contains(term.ToLower())
                  select new { r.Description }).Distinct();
    return Json(result, JsonRequestBehavior.AllowGet);
}
```

Any idea where I'm going wrong?

Answer (score 26, accepted):

As you have pointed in a comment to Narendra answer, the problem is with `messages` option. As answered [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13283272/autocomplete-experimental-messages-option-no-results), `results` property, in `messages` option, must be a function instead of a string

```
jQuery(...).autocomplete({
    messages : {
        noResults : '',
        results : function(resultsCount) {}
    }
});
```

Comment: I had worked around this by simply commenting out the messages section, but you are correct, so thanks. Good to know!

Answer (score 0):

Seems like you are referring to a variable and trying to access the same as a function.

```
__response: function( content ) {
var message;
this._superApply( arguments );
if ( this.options.disabled || this.cancelSearch ) {
    return;
}
if ( content && content.length ) {
    message = this.options.messages.results=content;
```

Just change the code assign the content to result and it would work.

Comment: well, yes, that much I know from the error message. :) What I don't see is what's causing it. 
I was able to make the error go away by commenting out the "messages:" section of the autocomplete call. I will have to read up on that to understand it better.